# PHP - Interrupting or suspending pthread's execution

Tags: php, pthreads

How to interrupt an execution of a thread from the main context?

In the snippet below - how would one go about stopping the action that the thread does without destroying it?

```
class ReadFileThread extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($file, $chunk = 1024)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        $this->chunk = $chunk;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        if(is_file($this->file) && is_readable($this->file))
        {
            $fh = fopen($this->file, 'rb');

            while(!feof($fh))
            {
                $content = fread($fh, $this->chunk);
            }

            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
}

$num = 10;
$threads = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    $thread = new ReadFileThread('/path/to/10gig_file.txt', 1024);

    $threads[] = $thread;

    // I start the thread, now it's detached from the main context and is reading the file asynchronously
    $thread->start();
}

// The interesting part - I want to random 1 thread whose operation of file reading I want to interrupt
$to_interrupt = $threads[rand(0, $num)];

// How to interrupt the thread without destroying it? I want its context preserved
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RandomSeeds answer is close, but open to race conditions.

```
<?php
class FileReader extends Thread {
    public $file;
    public $pause;

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->pause = false;
    }

    public function run() {
        if (($handle = fopen($this->file, "rb"))) {
            $len = 0;
            do {
                $this->synchronized(function(){
                    if ($this->paused) {
                        printf(
                            "\npausing %lu ...\n", $this->getThreadId());
                        $this->wait();
                    }
                });

                $data = fread($handle, 1024);
                $len += strlen($data);

                if (($len % 2) == 0) {
                    printf( 
                        "\r\rread %lu", $len);
                }
            } while (!feof($handle));

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

    public function pause() {
        return $this->synchronized(function(){
            return ($this->paused = true);
        });
    }

    public function unpause() {
        return $this->synchronized(function(){
            $this->paused = false;      
            if ($this->isWaiting()) {
                return $this->notify();
            }
        });
    }
}

function do_something($time) {
    $start = time();

    while (($now = time()) < ($start + $time)) {
        usleep(100);
        if (($now % 2) == 0) {
            echo ".";
        }
    }

    echo "\n";
}

$reader = new FileReader("/path/to/big/file.ext");
$reader->start();

sleep(2);
$reader->pause();
do_something(rand(2, 4));
$reader->unpause();
sleep(2);
$reader->pause();
do_something(rand(2, 4));
$reader->unpause();
sleep(2);
$reader->pause();
do_something(rand(2, 4));
$reader->unpause();
?>
```

It is important that variables used for purposes of synchronization are only ever access in synchronized blocks, I have omitted the implementation of a stop/quit function but it's logic is much the same, as RandomSeeds example shows.

Race conditions lurk within:

```
public function mine($data) {
    /* anyone can set doSynchronization at any time */
    if ($this->doSynchronization) {

        $this->synchronize(function(){
            /* checking the predicate in here is safer */
            $this->wait();
        });
    }
}
```

Good:

```
public function mine($data) {
    $this->synchronize(function(){
        if ($this->doSynchronization) {
            $this->wait();
        }
    });
}
```

Extreme:

```
public function mine($data) {
    $this->synchronize(function(){
        while ($this->doSynchronization) {
            $this->wait();
        }
    });
}
```

The posix standard would always have you write it the extreme way, I'm not so fussed, whatever works for you. The reason for this extreme code is, allowances must be made for a thread to receive a signal other than the one it is waiting on, many low level signals may result in a thread waking from a call to pthread_cond_wait; checking the predicate in a loop like that guards against what the specification calls spurious wakeups ... but such extreme measures can also lead to ill side effects; the reason those threads receive the low level signal is because it is necessary for them to take some action of some kind, ignoring that can easily cause a different part of the stack to deadlock because it expected your thread to die (or do something else, die is an example) when it was signalled ...

Comment: Always a pleasure :) further reading: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782 (in case you haven't seen it already)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't arbitrarily pause a concurrent thread, but you can send a notification to it. The other thread must cooperate and willingly pause itself when it receives the notification.

Example:

```
<?php

class MyThread extends Thread {

    private $pauseRequested = false;
    private $stopRequested = false;

    public function pause() {
        $this->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->pauseRequested = true;
        }, $this);
    }

    public function resume() {
        $this->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->pauseRequested = false;
            $thread->notify();
        }, $this);

    }

    public function stop() {
        $this->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->stopRequested = true;
        }, $this);
    }

    public function run() {
        echo 'Thread started!' . PHP_EOL;
        while (!$this->stopRequested) {

            // do the actual work
            echo 'Working...';
            sleep(1);

            // check if we have been requested to pause
            $this->synchronized(function($thread){
                if ($this->pauseRequested) {
                    echo 'Paused...';
                    $thread->wait(); // this is where the magic happens
                }
            }, $this);
        }

        if ($this->stopRequested) {
            echo PHP_EOL . 'Stopped!' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}


$t = new MyThread();
$t->start();
sleep(5);

$t->pause();
sleep(2);

$t->resume();
sleep(5);

$t->stop();

// wait for $t to complete
$t->join(); 

?>
```

Comment: @JoeWatkins Thanks for your explanations, I fixed my code just in case someone feels like reusing it. I'm not 100% sure I got everything right, would you mind proof-reading my edit? Notice I didn't synchronise access to `$this->stopRequested`. Since the flag cannot be unset, I assume it is safe, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, and following the same logic, is it safe to *not* sychronise `MyThread::stop()`?

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped immensely. However, Joe's example worked perfectly for me so being unable to accept both answer - I'm upvoting you on this one :)

Comment: @Furicane I agree that Joe Watkin's answer is the best one, no problem. I'm glad I could help anyways.

Comment: very close, in the real world though, the ::stop method should ::notify the object because it could be waiting, and after you called ::stop you will not be calling any other methods that can notify ... kudos on the attempt by the way, I love that people are getting to know what they are doing without help :D

Comment: the rule of thumb should be "variables used for synchronization should only ever be accessed in synchronized blocks", but as you rightly observe there is a logical way around it in some cases, all the same, some rules are just not worth breaking. You needn't call the whole block synchronized, swap that for do {} while and make a synchronized call to access stopRequested at the top of the block, breaking on a positive ( hint: the result of a call to synchronize is whatever the block returns )

Answer (score 0):

Never used pthreads, tbh, but have you tried making a public boolean flag inside the thread class ?

Comment: I have, however I don't see how that could help me interrupt the fopen/fread that's happening inside the thread. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I assume that changing the flag is visible from the already running "run" method. If this flag will change to "false", lets call it "readTheFile", you would just skip the "fread" loop until the flag will be changed back to "true". Doing it like this gives you more control over what is happening inside this thread; you can even get the current position (ftell ), store it, close the file handle. The main loop will be still running waiting for "readTheFile" to change. If its "true" open the file again and continue reading where you left off.